# How to get parameterized value from Jenkins python

Tags: python, search, jenkins, collect

I use python-jenkins. I need to collect parameterized value from any job all job.

i don't undestand, how i can do it?!
my part of script:

```
...
s = jenkins.Jenkins(server_url, user, pwd)
try:
    job_name = 'job_name'                  
    build_num = s.get_job_info(job_name)['lastBuild']['number']
    while build_num>0: 
        try: 
            build_info = s.get_build_info(job_name,build_num)
            build_info_actions = build_info['actions']
            print(build_info_actions)
...
```

I view some information

```
[{'parameters': [{'value': '12345', 'name': 'name1', '_class': 'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'}, {'value': 'value2', 'name': 'name2', '_class': 'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'}, {'value': 'http://some_URL', 'name': 'Url1', '_class': 'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'}, {'value': '', 'name': 'Url2', '_class': 'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'}], '_class': 'hudson.model.ParametersAction'}, {'_class':'hudson.model.CauseAction', 'causes': [{'note': None, '_class': 'hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause', 'shortDescription': 'Started by  host NameHost', 'addr': 'some.address'}]}, {'_class': 'jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction'}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

how can i collect all information and save to file like this:

```
name1 , 12345, name2, value2, Url1, http://some_URL ...
```

**BIG** Thx for you help!
Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Not sure if I got the question right. Do you want to know how to read the values from the dictionary? Basically it's just that and some string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, you right.  I need this.  Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [{'parameters': [{'value': '12345', 'name': 'name1'}]}]
```

Here

```
x
```

is list (`[]`) of dictionaries that might also contain lists with dictionaries.

e.g. accessing `value` is done like that:

`x[0]` is the first element in the list, since this is a dictionary you get its key `parameters` like

```
x[0]['parameters']
```

This is also a list of dictionaries, first element is

```
x[0]['parameters'][0]
```

and the key `value` is

```
x[0]['parameters'][0]['value']
```

Then just contatenate the strings and write to a file.

Comment: You ok from here? Or do you need further infos?

Comment: one more question. How can i get parameters if the are not taken in [] ?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean. You can iterate lists with `for d in y`. If `y` is a list of dictionaries, you can get the keys of the dictionary `d` with `d.keys()` or iterate the dictionary with `for key in d`. Since `d.keys()` is an iterator use `list(d.keys())` if you need a list, but `for a in d.keys()` also works.